# Java List<E> to Map<P, List<E>> were key is some property of E and value is E with that property

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like how to convert Java List to Map. Were key in a map is some property of the list element (different elements might have the same property) and value is a list of those list items (having the same property).
eg.`List<Owner> --> Map<Item, List<Owner>>`. I found a few `List` to `Map` questions, but it was not I want to do.

What I came with is:

```
    List<Owner> owners = new ArrayList<>(); // populate from file

    Map<Item, List<Owner>> map = new HashMap<>();

    owners.parallelStream()
            .map(Owner::getPairStream)
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .forEach(pair -> {
                map.computeIfPresent(pair.getItem(), (k,v)-> {
                    v.add(pair.getOwner());
                    return v;
                });
                map.computeIfAbsent(pair.getItem(), (k) -> {
                    List<Owner> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(pair.getOwner());
                    return list;
                });
            });
```

[PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/hsrxHW5R)

I can put `forEach` part to a separate method, but it still feels too verbose. Plus I made a `Pair` class just to make it work. I tried to look in to `Collectors` but couldn't get my head around to do what I wanted.

Comment: Turning `List<A>` into `Map<B, List<A>>` doesn't sound like conversion, that sounds like you just want to declare a `Map<B, List<A>>` and then literally just add lists without doing anything to them whatsoever. What are you trying to do, conceptually, that you think you need this for? (i.e. what problem did you originally have that you thought this would be a good solution for?)

Comment: @Mike I was doing some coding challenge (HashCode picture slide challenge) then I came up with this idea. How should I edit the title to make it clear enough? I often have trouble to express my mind. If you look at paste bin you can see what I want to do.

Comment: `key in a map is some property of the list element` Is this key unique?  So do you want to fetch an existing list if possible and create a new list if it doesn't exist for that key?

Comment: One thing in particular I see is that `map` is not thread safe and you're using a `parallelStream`.  Can't work, you'll need to a thread safe map instead.  In general Java's streams do not like sharing mutable state.

Comment: @markspace I updated the description a bit. hope now is a bit clearer. Feel free to update more (I'm not a native English speaker). I know my solution is not great. I put it only to show what I want to do. Ideally, I would like to `.collect()` it to  Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where this is, you can simplify your code by using `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Item, List<Owner>> map = owners.stream()
        .flatMap(Owner::getPairStream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getItem, 
                Collectors.mapping(Pair::getOwner, 
                                   Collectors.toList())));
```

You can also dispense with the `Pair` class by using `SimpleEntry`:

```
Map<Item, List<Owner>> map = owners.stream()
    .flatMap(owner -> owner.getItems()
                    .stream()
                    .map(item -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(item, owner)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, 
                   Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, 
                                     Collectors.toList())));
```

**Note** that I'm assuming that `Item` has `equals` and `hashCode` overridden accordingly.

Side notes:

- You can use `map.merge` instead of successively calling `map.computeIfPresent` and `map.computeIfAbsent`
- `HashMap` and `parallelStream` make a bad combination (`HashMap` isn't thread-safe)

Comment: Since the OP wants to use `parallelStream`, would it be possible to use a collector like `Collectors.groupingByConcurrent` to accomplish their goal?

Comment: It looks like what I wanted. By any chance you know a nice site (not talking about Java docs)  to help me get a grasp in `Collectors`? If you think the question could be asked clearer please update it if you can. Or let me know I update it.

Comment: @markspace I've actually never used `groupingByConcurrent`. When I think and read about it, I don't fully grasp the difference it would make. It doesn't seem to make a difference other than in the type of the returned map (and, I suppose, in the actual accumulation of values) when I compare the resulting map to that of a simple `groupingBy` on a parallel stream... Maybe that's a question I should ask...

Comment: @my- I find the question clear and simple enough, and the code you linked to makes it complete. It just takes some thinking :-)